# How to create parameterised webhook url on gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

The use-case would be to trigger certain jobs, only after an **MR** is not in **WIP** anymore.

The idea what I'm exploring is to create a **merge-request webhook**, that would trigger a pipeline.

However in order to do this, I have to get the `ref` from the webhook's request body to call the trigger accordingly.
What options do I have?

Running a server just for processing the *webhook* and redirecting to the correct endpoint is not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

> Running a server just for processing the webhook and redirecting to the correct endpoint

I dont see any other way. I'm in same boat. Gonna use Heroku for just this bit. Oh well.